# Apache modules installed but htaccess caching doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vps

I am trying to set up caching through .htaccess rules on my VPS server. I made sure mod_expires and mime type detection was installed but when I run my site through gtmetrix it shows I do not have caching enabled. Here are my .htaccess rules:

```
# Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>

# Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
#month
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
#week
  <filesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </filesMatch>
#day
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers

# Turn ETags Off
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None

# Remove Last-Modified Header
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Last-Modified
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Last-Modifed in the FilesMatch block. 
Something like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|ico)$">
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
  Header  set Cache-Control "public"
  Header  set Last-Modified "Mon, 31 Aug 2009 00:00:00 GMT"
  Header  unset ETag 
  Header  append Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch >
```

Comment: I added it and still no luck.

Comment: Make sure that mod_headers.c is enabled ? Try to remove <ifModule mod_headers.c> blocks. In that case you will get an error, if module mod_headers.c isn't enabled.

Comment: Ok I removed the mod_headers.c blocks and didn't get an error.

Comment: To exclude overriding problem with htaccess, could you try to move all of this from htaccess file into the httpd.conf file and restart Apache server ?

Comment: Ok, I did that but it still isn't working. The page speed addon for Chrome is still showing a (1 day) cache.